# JPA: what is the default accessType FIELD or PROPERTY?

Tags: jpa

JPA: what is the default accessType FIELD or PROPERTY?

```
public class Foo {
   @Column(length=10)
   public String name;

   //@Column(length=10)
   public String getName() {
   }
}
```

It is not mentioned in docs.

Comment: Persistent fields shouldn't be public according to the specification (https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html):

"The instance variables of a class must be private, protected, or package visibility independent of whether field access or property access is used. When property access is used, the property accessor methods must be public or protected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official specification

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf

**2.3.1 Default Access Type Page 23**

By  default,  a  single  access  type  (field  or  property  access)  applies  to  an  entity  hierarchy.  The  default access  type  of  an  entity  hierarchy  is  determined  by  the  placement  of  mapping  annotations  on  the attributes  of  the  entity  classes  and  mapped  superclasses  of  the  entity  hierarchy  that  do  not  explicitly
specify an access type.

An access type is explicitly specified by means of the Access annotation [6]
, as described in section 2.3.2.

2.3.2
Explicit Access Type
An access type for an individual entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class can be specified for that class independent of the default 
for the entity hierarchy by means of the Access annotation applied to the class.  This explicit access type specification does not affect the access type of other entity classes or mapped superclasses in the entity hierarchy. The following rules apply:
•
When Access(FIELD) is  applied  to  an  entity  class,  mapped  superclass,  or  embeddable class, mapping annotations may be placed on the instance variables of that class, and the persistence  provider  runtime  accesses  persistent  state  via  the  instance  variables  defined  by  the class.  All non-transient instance variables that are not annotated with the Transient annotation  are  persistent.

When  Access(FIELD) is  applied  to  such  a  class,  it  is  possible  to
selectively  designate  individual  attributes  with
in  the  class  for  property  access. To  specify  a
persistent property for access by the persistence provider runtime, that property must be desig-
nated 
Access(PROPERTY)
.
[8]
 The behavior is undefined if mapping annotations are placed
on any properties defined by the class for which 
Access(PROPERTY) is not specified. Persistent  state  inherited  from  superclasses  is  accessed  in  accordance  with  the  access  types  of
those superclasses.

Conclusion:
**First annotation on field or getter determines access for whole entity.**

When Access(PROPERTY) is used ...rules chaged

```
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
@Entity(name="STUDENT")
public class Student { 
 ... all mus be annotated on FIELD

}
```

Comment: Why JPA does not specify one way for consistency for whole project?

Comment: how to determine the first annotation on field or getter? The reflection does not have that information.